# Crash in UITableViewController after numberOfSectionsInTableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have subclassed an `UITableViewController`, which I am instantiating trough a segue.

It seems that the table view controller is correctly instantiated as `viewDidLoad` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` are being called. 
In fact, `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is called even **twice**. When it is called first, it has a valid value for `tableView`, when it is called for the second time (right after the first call), `tableView` is `nil`.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [super numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView] + 1 ;
}
```

I am using a static cell (in section 0, row 0) which I have set up in Interface Builder and I am adding a dynamic number of rows in the second section (section 1). That is why I have added 1 to `[super numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView]`. There is no custom code in the parent's tableView class, everything is just set up in Interface Builder.

All **outlets** seem to be set correctly:

[image]

When the execution of the code continues, the app crashes with the error message:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]`

Do you have any idea on what could cause the error?

Comment: provide code for the parent tableview controller

Comment: My guess would be that you have not implemented `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`.  You need to return the number of rows in each section (super for section 0 and the appropriate number for your added section).  Then, you need to do the same with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [super numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView] + 1 ;
}
```

Basically means that every time `numberOfSectionsInTableView` gets called the number of sections in the table will increase by 1. That being said, if you are only ever going to have two sections in the table, you'd be better off with `return 2;`.

Now, on to your error. It's kind of hard to say considering I don't know the exact context or where the error occurred, but my first guess is that the crash happened in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because your datasource is either nil or and is an empty array.